# Some driver breaks sleep mode in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, sleep

Today sleep mode in my Windows 10 stopped working. It powering off displays, but nothing else. Coolers and PSU continue working, USB devices powered, etc.

After a lot of research, I found out that the reason is some driver.

When i selecting in msconfig to load only base drivers and services - sleep mode works as it should.

If i only manually disable all startup items and non-Microsoft services - sleep mode still broken.

How can i determine and disable driver, that breaks sleep mode?

Comment: Perhaps use the Manufacturer's Driver Update App to update all drivers. See if this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer here:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/about-windows-being-unable-to-enter-sleep-mode-but/c0174cff-a1a6-4a0f-a59b-fea448ba2a5e

Soft "UU Game Booster" changes sleep mode to away mode.

Fix is to deny Away mode.

Maybe will be useful for someone

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confusing sleep mode with hibernate. Sleep mode uses a small amount of power and keeps functioning and is quick to return. Hibernate on the other hand saves the information and reduces the systems functions further consuming less or no power which will take longer to start back up from later.

You should see the hibernate option when you click the power icon under the windows menu. If you don't you might need to enable this feature by going to the control panel > system and security > Power Options > choose what the power button does > Under shutdown settings > enable hibernate. If it's greyed out there is an option above that allows you to edit unselectable items. This requires an admin level permissions.

It maybe your graphics driver that preventing hibernation. If your power plan setting in your graphics card or windows powercfg is set to performance it also might be preventing hibernation but by enabling this option you can forcibly select it.

If you are set to determine what the driver is you can use the command "powercfg -lastwake" to find out what program woke your device last. Depending on the driver associated with the program you may be able to get away with disabling it and using a windows generic driver if it exists. You should note that if you disable it you may find yourself lacking in its respective functionality.

Hope this helps.